# AntTweakBar key input and GLFW 3

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, graphics, 3d

AntTweakBar despite being "not supported" anymore is still **widely used** or at least **appears to be.** However, I cant get it to accept input from the keyboard with GLFW 3.2. When I create a simple GUI panel and a tweak bar with

```
TwBar *myBar;
myBar = TwNewBar("NameOfMyTweakBar");
double speed = .3;
TwAddVarRW(myBar, "speed", TW_TYPE_DOUBLE, &speed, "label='Rot Speed' min=0 max=2 step=0.01 keyIncr=s keyDecr=S help='Rotation speed (turns/second)' ");
```

and then try to get it to accept key input it returns 0. I've tried the char callback as well with no luck. Is this library just hopelessly outdated? **What other similar libraries are there to choose from?**

```
void glfwKeyCallback(GLFWwindow *myWin, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    cout << "TwEventKeyGLFW = " << TwEventKeyGLFW(key, action) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are working versions on github for GLFW3 such as [AntTweakBarGLFW3](https://github.com/sasmaster/AntTweakBarGLFW3).